# Count the most frequently used words in an Excel column containing A LOT of text?

Tags: vba, excel

I have a large spreadsheet and I'd like to perform a word count on a specific column to figure out the most frequently used words. This column contains a very large amount of data and text.

For example, "Employee was climbing a ladder to retrieve merchandise off the top shelf. The ladder began to sway and the employee lost his balance and fell. Injury to the right leg". There are about 1000 different records like this. I was hoping use a pivot table to figure out what the most frequently used words are throughout all the cells in this column.

I'm not sure how to do this. Can anyone assist in how to do this?

Currently using the following code:

```
Option Explicit

Sub MakeWordList()
    Dim InputSheet As Worksheet
    Dim WordListSheet As Worksheet
    Dim PuncChars As Variant, x As Variant
    Dim i As Long, r As Long
    Dim txt As String
    Dim wordCnt As Long
    Dim AllWords As Range
    Dim PC As PivotCache
    Dim PT As PivotTable

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Set InputSheet = ActiveSheet
    Set WordListSheet = Worksheets.Add(after:=Worksheets(Sheets.Count))
    WordListSheet.Range("A1") = "All Words"
    WordListSheet.Range("A1").Font.Bold = True
    InputSheet.Activate
    wordCnt = 2
    PuncChars = Array(".", ",", ";", ":", "'", "!", "#", _
        "$", "%", "&", "(", ")", " - ", "_", "--", "+", _
        "=", "~", "/", "\", "{", "}", "[", "]", """", "?", "*")
    r = 1

'   Loop until blank cell is encountered
    Do While Cells(r, 1) <> ""
'       covert to UPPERCASE
        txt = UCase(Cells(r, 1))
'       Remove punctuation
        For i = 0 To UBound(PuncChars)
            txt = Replace(txt, PuncChars(i), "")
        Next i
'       Remove excess spaces
        txt = WorksheetFunction.Trim(txt)
'       Extract the words
        x = Split(txt)
        For i = 0 To UBound(x)
            WordListSheet.Cells(wordCnt, 1) = x(i)
            wordCnt = wordCnt + 1
        Next i
    r = r + 1
    Loop

'   Create pivot table
    WordListSheet.Activate
    Set AllWords = Range("A1").CurrentRegion
    Set PC = ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Add _
        (SourceType:=xlDatabase, _
        SourceData:=AllWords)
    Set PT = PC.CreatePivotTable _
        (TableDestination:=Range("C1"), _
        TableName:="PivotTable1")
    With PT
        .AddDataField .PivotFields("All Words")
        .PivotFields("All Words").Orientation = xlRowField
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Do you have one word per cell? Or does each cell have some number of words?

Comment: Each cell has a number of words. For instance, the example I gave about the employee falling off the ladder would just be in one cell.

Comment: This is not difficult with a *VBA Macro*  Are you O.K. with this approach??

Comment: Not particularly comfortable using VBA, though I am attempting to learn it. I've added the code I am currently using above.

Comment: I'm noticing some good solutions.  If you implement any of the ideas below, you may want to consider incorporating something to eliminate the punctuation, and make sure that things are uppercase, as in your original code.  If you like one of the solutions, and are having trouble, perhaps you can ask them to add that to their code.

Comment: ^ I was going to note that you may want to `Trim` c in my below solution, or perhaps Replace punctuation with nothing :)

Comment: You're "attempting to learn" VBA? From the code you posted, it looks like you've between at it for a while. Keep it up! And you can incorporate some of your ideas in my answer if you want.

Comment: @BruceWayne - psst - that wasn't original code! (not that there is much of a need for such a thing nowadays, thanks to resources like SO!)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's a quick and dirty macro (I'm feeling extra helpful today).  Put this in your workbook module.  Note: I'm assuming the sheet you will have active is the one with all the text in column A.

```
Sub Test()
Dim lastRow&, i&, tempLastRow&
Dim rawWS As Worksheet, tempWS As Worksheet

Set rawWS = ActiveSheet
Set tempWS = Sheets.Add
tempWS.Name = "Temp"
rawWS.Activate

'tempWS.Columns(1).Value = rawWS.Columns(1).Value
tempLastRow = 1

With rawWS
    .Columns("A:A").TextToColumns Destination:=Range("A1"), DataType:=xlDelimited, _
                                  TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=True, Tab:=True, _
                                  Semicolon:=False, Comma:=False, Space:=True, Other:=False, TrailingMinusNumbers:=True

    lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

    For i = lastRow To 1 Step -1
        .Rows(i).EntireRow.Copy
        tempWS.Range("A" & tempLastRow).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll, Transpose:=True
        ' tempWS.Range ("A" & tempLastRow)
        tempLastRow = tempWS.Cells(tempWS.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1
    Next i
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
End With

With tempWS
    ' Now, let's get unique words and run a count
    .Range("A:A").Copy .Range("C:C")
    .Range("C:C").RemoveDuplicates Columns:=1, Header:=xlNo
    tempLastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp).Row

    .Range(.Cells(1, 4), .Cells(tempLastRow, 4)).FormulaR1C1 = "=COUNTIF(C[-3],RC[-1])"
    .Sort.SortFields.Clear
    .Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range("D1:D1048576") _
                              , SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlDescending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
    With .Sort
        .SetRange Range("C1:D1048576")
        .Header = xlGuess
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply
    End With

End With

End Sub
```

Basically, it creates a new sheet, counts all the individual words, and puts the words (and count) in a column, sorted by most used.  You can tweak as needed.

Note: I made this before you added your code.  It doesn't create a pivot table, but from what I understand you need, a Pivot Table would be overkill if you just need the most used words.  But, let me know if you need any edits or changes!

Comment: Hi, I am attempting to run your code, did you mean to comment out the two snippets of code 
`'tempWS.Columns(1).Value = rawWS.Columns(1).Value`
 and 
`' tempWS.Range ("A" & tempLastRow)`?
 When I run the code with those sections commented out I get nothing in the temp WS, when I remove the comment from both I get the error "Invalid use of property" on the line `' tempWS.Range ("A" & tempLastRow)`, and when I only remove the first comment the code will run but it does not count the words properly.

Comment: @Tydis - It'd been a while since I wrote this -- but yes the `tempWS.Range("A" & tempLastRow)` line should be commented out. You're getting an error there because that line doesn't actually *do* anything. (I forget why I included it, even if commented out).  It *looks* like that `tempWS...Value = rawWS...Value` should *not* be commented out if you need data in the temp sheet.  As you noted, without it you don't have any information in Temp WS' column A to actually copy...When you run it, how doesn't it count the words properly? Does it give error, or simply provide an incorrect count?

Comment: I'm not sure what I had done wrong earlier, but after copying and pasting the macro directly into my sheet I was able to get it to run. Thanks for the reply!

Answer (score 6):

Here's a routine to display each word and the number of times it appears (using `Split` and `Collection`s)

Usage: `CountTheWordsInRange Range("A1:A4")`

```
Sub CountTheWordsInRange(RangeToCheck As Range)

Dim wordList As New Collection
Dim keyList As New Collection
Dim c
For Each c In RangeToCheck
    Dim words As Variant
    words = Split(c, " ") 'Pick a delimiter
    For Each w In words
        Dim temp
        temp = -1
        On Error Resume Next
        temp = wordList(w)
        On Error GoTo 0
        If temp = -1 Then
            wordList.Add 1, Key:=w
            keyList.Add w, Key:=w
        Else
            wordList.Remove (w)
            keyList.Remove (w)
            wordList.Add temp + 1, w
            keyList.Add w, Key:=w
        End If
    Next w
Next c
'Here we can display the word counts
'KeyList is a collection that contains each word
'WordList is a collection that contains each amount
Dim x
For x = 1 To wordList.Count
    With Sheets("Sheet1")
        .Cells(x, "E").Value = keyList(x)  'Display Word in column "E"
        .Cells(x, "F").Value = wordList(x) 'Display Count in column "F"
    End With
Next x

End Sub
```

Results:

[image: Results]

Comment: Would it be possible to modify this code so that it splits into 3 words rather than one? Like "Hello said the" would be counted as 2 in your example. I'm trying to eliminate common words like he, I, it, the, and, etc. and I felt like counting for 3 words together would be better suited to identifying patterns. Thanks!

Comment: @Tydis it's doable, but I'm curious how you'd like the words broken out. For example, should the first one return `Hello said the` and `said the chef` only?

Comment: I guess optimally it would search for the same 3 words together, but I have been thinking about this all day and I think that would be very complicated to do, and likely take a long time to run, especially with the amount of data I am parsing each time I run this macro.